# Как я могу выполнить sql запрос проверяя изменения в БД?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Необходимо выполнить запрос, и по выполнению некоторых частей запроса, просмотреть результат в таблицах. После просмотра данных нужно продолжить выполнение запроса.

Comment: запрос выполняется один раз и весь целиком. и от человека который "будет смотреть" это никак не зависит

Comment: @Mike спасибо. Тогда логичнее будет использовать несколько запросов?

Comment: Видимо да. хотя совершенно не ясно что вы имели ввиду. как например можно смотреть результат в таблицах по частям запроса. запрос если что то меняет - то одну таблицу, например, а не несколько. у меня подозрение что вы "запросом" называете что то не то ...

Comment: @Mike возможно. Я пишу скрипт, который создает таблицу и впоследствии взаимодействует с ней и удаляет строки из других таблиц.

Comment: @Mike строго говоря, существуют транзакции, которые позволяют осуществить задуманное.